# Moodle API cant create users with HTML tag in description

Tags: php, html, tinymce, registration, moodle

i have a long string about student and need this string add to desc.

```
$core_external = new core_user_external();

$UserFields = array(
    'username' => $_GET['username'],
    'password' => $_GET['password'],
    'firstname' => $_GET['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $_GET['lastname'],
    'email' => $_GET['email'],
    'city' => $_GET['city'],
    'country' => $_GET['country'],
    'description' => $_GET['desc']
);

$usersids = $core_external->create_users(array($UserFields));
```

if i try send 'desc' like `"<br>sdfasdfasdf<br>"` get next error

Invalid external api parameter: the value is `"<br>sdfasdfasdf<br>"`, the server was expecting "text" type
Error code: invalidparameter

how can add HTML tags in get or post methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use $_GET directly, it can introduce SQL injection.

Use one of these instead

```
'description' => optional_param('desc', '', PARAM_TEXT);
```

or

```
'description' => required_param('desc', PARAM_TEXT);
```

Use the relevant PARAM_XXX option for each of the parameters.

If you take a look at `core_user_external::create_users_parameters()` it will show which types to use for each parameter.

Comment: in library i found next:   'description' => new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'User profile description, no HTML', VALUE_OPTIONAL), really? core function dont take html tags? it's possible avoid this? or need switch VALUE_OPTIONAL somehow, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `\n` instead of `<br>`

```
\nsdfasdfasdf\n
```